# accessing 2nd level of DOM tree parent()

Tags: jquery, forms, parent

Say I have a form, on clicking a button on that form, another form pops up. The user inputs to this 'popup' form and on submit I want the input value to be sent to a hidden input value on the original form.

So does the original form of which the new form sprung from count as the 2nd level parent? the grandparent ;)

This is a method I am trying to look into to solve my problem. Feel free to suggest any other ways :D

thanks,

**EDIT:** my solution:

```
$(".pass_submit").live('click', function(event) {
    var formid = $(this).closest('form')
    var plaintext = $('#pass').val();
    $(formid).find('.password').val(plaintext); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no child forms concept. We should not use nested forms.

If you want to access the parent with DOM, it is quite simple like this
var p = document.getElementById ("div1").parentNode;

Comment: dnt understand how that works for my situation, in leymans terms please ( i am a beginner ) lol. I have added jsfiddle to demonstrate my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Ok lets do like this. Dont need to use child form concept.

function StoreInHidden()
{
document.getElementById ("hiddenname").value = document.getElementById ("x").value;
document.getElementById ("pop").style.display='none';
}

function Show()
{
document.getElementById ("pop").style.display='';

}

Comment: dnt understand at all what you are doing here :S